# Error 404 after rewrite query strings with htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, 404, query-string

I'm trying to redirect the URLs of a client's website like this:

```
www.localsite.com/immobile.php?id_immobile=24
```

In something like this:

```
www.localsite.com/immobile/24.php
```

I'm using this rule in *.htaccess* but it returns a 404 error page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_immobile=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^immobile\.php$ http://localsite.com/immobile/%1.php? [L]
```

I have tried many other rules, but none work. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule id_immobile/(.*)/? immobile.php?id_immobile=$1 [NC,L]
```

Let me know how that looks and what the end result is if it doesn't work...

### Edit

Please could you just test something for me by trying this one (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963051/i-want-to-remove-question-mark-php-extension-from-the-url-using-htaccess)):-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?id=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?id=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I've tryed with your code but it doesn't work.

The URL before mod_rewrite and after is the same:

http://www.localsite.com/immobile.php?id_immobile=XXX

Comment: Are you sure you implemented it correctly as it should definitely have changed the URL. What else do you have in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: This is my .htaccess (without the MOD_Deflate compression):

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.terrenocasa.it/ [R=301,L]
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule id_immobile/(.*)/? immobile.php?id_immobile=$1 [NC,L]
    
    errorDocument 404 http://www.terrenocasa.it/errore.php
      
    <Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>

Comment: Sorry for the format. It looks very confused. But I can't answer to my question for now with preformatted text.

Comment: @Christian - please see my updated answer.

Comment: Same problem for the query strings. The URL is the same before and after. In addition, the menu pages (about, contact, etc.) give error 404. Thank you for your time.

Comment: See extra two lines at the top of my edited answer - please add and retest.

Comment: Nothing to do. Not working for query strings (the URL doesn't change). The error for menu pages is this: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_immobile=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^immobile\.php$ http://localsite.com/immobile/%1.php? [L]
```

Like you say in your first sentence, you want to **redirect** from one URL to the other. Currently your `RewriteRule` performs an *internal rewrite*, not an *external redirect*, which I believe is your goal. Simply add the `R=301` flag to your current `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^immobile\.php$ http://localsite.com/immobile/%1.php? [R=301,L]
```

(Is there any reason to keep the `.php` extension?)

This should also come towards the top of your .htaccess file.

However, this is only half the process, which is probably why you are getting a 404. You will need to do an *internal rewrite* back to the actual URL (with a query string) in order to complete the process (careful to avoid a redirect/rewrite loop).

Comment: No, there is no reason to keep the php extension. I had already tried with R=301 but it didn't work. Maybe I've done things uncorrectly. Sorry for the ignorance. What do you mean with an internal rewrite to the actual URL? I have to do another RewriteRule in htaccess?

Comment: "it didn't work"? - You got a 404 presumably? Because... `/immobile/24.php` is your "pretty" URL - it is virtual and doesn't exist as an actual file on the system. You need to internally rewrite it back to the real URL ie. `/immobile.php?id_immobile=24`. You have presumably already changed all your links to the `/immobile/24.php` format? (I assume you are implementing "pretty" URLs?)

Comment: Geoff has been trying to do the second part (internal rewrite) for you. Geoff's code (top bit) should be used **in addition** to the redirect above (with the `R=301` flag). You need _both_ parts.

Comment: Take a deep breath, have a cup of tea... ;) Well, you did specifically ask about a "redirect" - which I have answered above. However, it does look like you are implementing what is commonly called "pretty (or user friendly) URLs" on an existing site. Is this the case? If so, you need to know the difference between an "external redirect" and an "internal rewrite". Also, if this is an existing site and you are _changing_ an existing URL structure (which is what I assumed) then you will need more than just a single rewrite.

Comment: Yes, it's an existing website done by another agency. The customer asked me if it was possible to change the URL, and I told him that I would try. But I do not understand this. If it is a complicated thing I tell him to let it go .. It is not the job for which he hired me. Thank you very much to you and @Geoff. Thank's.